# converting the code from console.log to innnerHTML (to show up in HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list

I am trying to build a todo list in html using JS.

I am able to prepare a list in the console in Google Chrome but I don't know the syntax to be used in printing the "list" to the browser.

please have a look at the following code:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var myCurrentList = [];
    while (true) {
        var questionAsked = prompt("please tell tell me what do you want to do");
        var userInput = ""
        if (questionAsked.toLowerCase() === "new") {
            userInput= prompt("enter the task")
            myCurrentList.push(userInput);

        }

        else if (questionAsked.toLowerCase() === "list") {
            for (var i = 0; i < myCurrentList.length ; i++) {
                console.log( (i+1) + '. ' + myCurrentList[i]);
            }
        }

        else if (questionAsked.toLowerCase() === "quit") {
            console.log("Thank you!");
            break
        }

        else {
            alert("please use the text from only 3 given options")
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive ToDo List</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>ToDo List Instructions</h1>
<ol>
    <li>to add a ToDo task please type "new"</li>
    <li>to view your current list please type "list"</li>
    <li>when done and want to quit,please type "quit"</li>
</ol>

<p id="infoSection"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="toDoListJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safer way to add elements is by using the DOM API (google 'mdn dom api').

`var myList = document.getElementById('my-list');
var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
newListItem.textContent = 'List item text.';
myList.appendChild(newListItem);`

This page is a good introduction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction